# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state_dict'

Tags: pytorch, torch

After completing one epoch, it gives an error and i installed all dependencies according to repo but still it gives an error.

```
conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
pip install opencv-python==4.4.0.46 termcolor==1.1.0 yacs==0.1.8
```

**Code**

```
import os
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import numpy as np
import pdb
 
try:
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    from apex import amp
except ImportError:
    amp = None

    def save_checkpoint(config, epoch, model, max_accuracy, optimizer, lr_scheduler, logger):
        save_state = {'model': model.state_dict(),
                      'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
                      'lr_scheduler': lr_scheduler.state_dict(),
                      'max_accuracy': max_accuracy,
                      'epoch': epoch,
                      'config': config}
        if config.AMP_OPT_LEVEL != "O0":
            save_state['amp'] = amp.state_dict()
    
        save_path = os.path.join(config.OUTPUT, f'ckpt_epoch_{epoch}.pth')
        logger.info(f"{save_path} saving......")
        torch.save(save_state, save_path)
        logger.info(f"{save_path} saved !!!")
```

**Log**

```
loss 6.5611 (6.7661)    grad_norm 2.8034 (nan)  mem 12138MB
[2023-06-08 11:25:02 deit_small_patch14_mask56_224_alpha1](main.py 488): INFO Train: [0/300][4970/5004] eta 0:00:37 lr 0.000051 time 1.0590 (1.1059)loss 6.6133 (6.7656)    grad_norm 2.9514 (nan)  mem 12138MB
[2023-06-08 11:25:13 deit_small_patch14_mask56_224_alpha1](main.py 488): INFO Train: [0/300][4980/5004] eta 0:00:26 lr 0.000051 time 1.1264 (1.1059)loss 6.3637 (6.7652)    grad_norm 3.3315 (nan)  mem 12138MB
[2023-06-08 11:25:24 deit_small_patch14_mask56_224_alpha1](main.py 488): INFO Train: [0/300][4990/5004] eta 0:00:15 lr 0.000051 time 1.0718 (1.1058)loss 6.5798 (6.7649)    grad_norm 2.6179 (nan)  mem 12138MB
[2023-06-08 11:25:35 deit_small_patch14_mask56_224_alpha1](main.py 488): INFO Train: [0/300][5000/5004] eta 0:00:04 lr 0.000051 time 1.0397 (1.1058)loss 6.7300 (6.7645)    grad_norm 3.6217 (nan)  mem 12138MB
[2023-06-08 11:25:38 deit_small_patch14_mask56_224_alpha1](main.py 497): INFO EPOCH 0 training takes 1:32:13
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 645, in <module>
    main(config)
  File "main.py", line 237, in main
    logger,
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/MixPro/utils.py", line 193, in save_checkpoint
    save_state['amp'] = amp.state_dict()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state_dict'
```

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the code.  What is ```amp```?   Where is this defined?

Comment: @ewokx sure i will include

Comment: You set ```amp = None``` in the import error exception block.  I would assume that since amp is None, this means the import failed; but since you caught that exception, you got no warning of this issue.  (I believe).  Try removing the try/except.